# MVC Conditional Vallidation RequiredIf

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using a custom validation, it works great for one value, however I need to check for Multiple values, for example:

> [RequiredIf( "Country", "Canada", "Postal Code is Required") ]
>   [RequiredIf("Country", "United States", "Zip Code is Required")]
>   public string PostalCode { get; set; }

I get Duplicate 'RequiredIf' attribute!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to clarify - you'd like the error message to be different depending on what country is selected?

Comment: The Duplicate error on building the project.  Yes I would like to get the error message depending on the country.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply the same data annotation twice to one property.

I don't know what your current `RequiredIfAttribute` code looks like, but I think you will have to write another custom validator that checks the selected country and adjusts the error message accordingly.

```
public class PostalCodeRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string errorMessage = "{0} is required.";
    public string CountryPropertyName { get; private set; }

    public PostalCodeRequiredAttribute(string countryPropertyName) : base(errorMessage)
    {
        CountryPropertyName = countryPropertyName;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(errorMessage, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null) return ValidationResult.Success;

        var countryPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(CountryPropertyName);
        string country = countryPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString();
        // assuming your country property is bound to a string

        string name;

        if (country == "United States")
             name = "Zip code";
        else if (country == "Canada")
             name = "Postal code";
        else
             return ValidationResult.Success;
             // assuming postal code not required for all other countries

        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(name));
    }
}
```

You would annotate like this, assuming your country property is called `Country`:

```
[PostalCodeRequired("Country")]
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately it did not work, here is the country property    [Required]
            public string Country { get; set; }.   You are correct postal code is not required for all other countries.

Comment: What specifically didn't work? Were there compile-time errors or did it not validate as expected? This code is for serverside validation only.

Comment: I made a new simple project and added your model, it works great; I think the problem is with my original project.  Thank you so much.

Comment: The problem was related to Javascript and Telerik ScriptRegistrar.  Thanks again

Comment: No problem. Glad you got things sorted out.

Comment: with C# 7.0, instead of using "Country" as a string, you can use  nameof(Country) and make it strongly typed.